# How to run code after some delay in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, delay

I'd like to execute a function after a certain delay after my Widget is built. What's the idiomatic way of doing this in Flutter?

What I'm trying to achieve:
I'd like to start with a default `FlutterLogo` Widget and then change its `style` property after some duration.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Figured it out

```dart
class AnimatedFlutterLogo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _AnimatedFlutterLogoState();
}

class _AnimatedFlutterLogoState extends State<AnimatedFlutterLogo> {
  Timer _timer;
  FlutterLogoStyle _logoStyle = FlutterLogoStyle.markOnly;

  _AnimatedFlutterLogoState() {
    _timer = new Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 400), () {
      setState(() {
        _logoStyle = FlutterLogoStyle.horizontal;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _timer.cancel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new FlutterLogo(
      size: 200.0,
      textColor: Palette.white,
      style: _logoStyle,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where did you import `Timer` from?

Comment: got it `import 'dart:async'`

Comment: one modification would be to put `timer = ...` in the `initState` override. That way, you have access to `widget` which is set in the `State<>` constructor.

Comment: Yes, both APIs run a block of code after a delay. But the accepted answer here actually cancels the execution of that block of code should the widget disappear. This was to prevent memory leaks, but it might not be necessary! I'd need a flutter developer to check if the timer/future still executes after a widget is disposed

Answer (score 504):

You can use [`Future.delayed`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-async/Future/Future.delayed.html) to run your code after some time. e.g.:

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {

// Here you can write your code

  setState(() {
    // Here you can write your code for open new view
  });

});
```

In setState function, you can write a code which is related to app UI e.g. refresh screen data, change label text, etc.

Comment: To avoid a warning check that your widget is still mounted before calling setState

Answer (score 136):

> **Trigger actions after countdown**

```
Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
  print("Yeah, this line is printed after 3 seconds");
});
```

> **Repeat actions**

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
  print(DateTime.now());
});
```

> **Trigger timer immediately**

```
Timer(Duration(seconds: 0), () {
  print("Yeah, this line is printed immediately");
});
```

Comment: This has the advantage over `Future.delayed` in that it can be canceled if stored in a variable!

Answer (score 102):

Just leaving here the snippet everyone is looking for:

```dart
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
  // Do something
});
```

Answer (score 37):

(Adding response on old q as this is the top result on google)

I tried yielding a new state in the callback within a bloc, and it didn't work.  Tried with Timer and Future.delayed.

However, what did work was...

```
await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));

yield newState;
```

Awaiting an empty future then running the function afterwards.

Answer (score 33):

`Synchronously`

```
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
    // Your code
});
```

---

`Asynchronously`

```
await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
```

Answer (score 14):

`Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)  , your_function)`

Answer (score 13):

Just adding more description over the above answers

The Timer functionality works with below duration time also:

```
const Duration(
      {int days = 0,
      int hours = 0,
      int minutes = 0,
      int seconds = 0,
      int milliseconds = 0,
      int microseconds = 0})
```

**Example:**

```
  Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
    print("print after every 3 seconds");
  });
```

Answer (score 13):

A quick way is using `Future.delayed` as below:

```
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10), (){
    print("Wait for 10 seconds");
});
```

or you can change duration to `milliseconds` like this:

```
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 3000), () {
        print("Wait for 3000 milliseconds");
});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
import 'dart:async';   
Timer timer;

void autoPress(){
  timer = new Timer(const Duration(seconds:2),(){
    print("This line will print after two seconds");
 });
}

autoPress();
```