# Flutter execute Function during time

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting value from http request within a function ,I need to execute a Function during a time (1 min) , So this function can repeat itself during this time (1 min) to analysis this value from http for every 1 min , can I do this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run code after some delay in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471063/how-to-run-code-after-some-delay-in-flutter)

Comment: @SanjaySharma The OP is asking for a method of periodically running code, not just once after a delay.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I think it has the required help. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59500175/4788260)

Comment: @SanjaySharma That should be added as an answer on **this** question with a link to that answer for credit as that question is not a duplicate.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore yes this should answer my question

Comment: An answer on this question should still be accepted or the question should be closed.

Comment: So change [this](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html) to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471063/how-to-run-code-after-some-delay-in-flutter/59500175#59500175) to accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Timer.periodic` to periodically run a function with the given time.

You can read more about this [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html).

Example usage:

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
  print(DateTime.now());
});
```

Comment: This can do with StramBuilder ?

Comment: @MohamedAlaa What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that I am using this `stream: Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1)).asyncMap((i) => _value()),` So Can I use Timer.periodic with StreamBuilder to make what I want

Comment: @MohamedAlaa I'm confused. Why do you need a `Stream`? I didn't see any info about that in your question.

Comment: Okay I understand what you say sorry if I not clear in my question

Comment: @MohamedAlaa If you provide more information I might be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you , you really helped me