# How can i "sleep" a Dart Porgram for 1.6 seconds

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to assign a double value as a sleep value in Dart? for example:`sleep(Duration(seconds: 1.6));`

Comment: You should never use `sleep` in Dart. Use instead a `Timer`: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.2/dart-async/Timer/Timer.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run code after some delay in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471063/how-to-run-code-after-some-delay-in-flutter)

Comment: Duration only takes integers as values. You could use milliseconds or combining seconds + milliseconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duration constructor has a number of optional parameters. You can use the milliseconds one to get 1.6 seconds delay

```
const Duration(milliseconds: 1600)
```

Comment: I actually did it with millisecons then thanks for the answer :D

Comment: @Janis you are welcome! You can mark this post as an answer then ;)

Answer (score 0):

Either use Timer class of you can also use Future.delayed() method to do the same.

Below is an example to Future.delayed method :

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1,milliseconds: 600), () {

// Here you can write your code


});
```

Answer (score 0):

And putting the milliseconds in a parameter:

```
int Tempo = 1600;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).