# Flutter await future for longer time?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to await a future for at least a second. However, the future can finish quite quickly, what method can I use to await the longer of 2 futures? Something like Future.any but the other way around.

Thank you!

Comment: what is your future method have inside its body?

Comment: You use future delay https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471063/how-to-run-code-after-some-delay-in-flutter

Comment: use `Future.wait`

Comment: What do you mean by "the longer"? You can await more than one Future with `await Future.wait([])` [docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.5.0/dart-async/Future/wait.html)

Comment: Yeap.. Future.delayed is the cleaner way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update I just used

```
await Future.wait([
  future1,
  future2,
]);
```

which waits for both to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can set a Timer and in its callback return the method. That way you can set the end to your like.