# There is a way to specify the time delay between audio tracks on the same playlist?

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I need to set a specific time delay between audio tracks on the playlist. Ex. 10 seconds delay. How could I achieve this?. Thanks in advance

Comment: this might answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471063/how-to-run-code-after-some-delay-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1. Create a silent audio track of the desired duration and insert it between each item in your `ConcatenatingAudioSource`.
2. Don't use `ConcatenatingAudioSource`, write your own playlist logic.

An example of the second approach could be:

```dart
// Maintain your own playlist position
int index = 0;
// Define your tracks
final tracks = <IndexedAudioSource>[ ... ];

// Auto advance with a delay when the current track completes
player.processingStateStream.listen((state) async {
  if (state == ProcessingState.completed && index < tracks.length) {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10));
    // You might want to check if another skip happened during our sleep
    // before we execute this skip.
    skipToIndex(index + 1);
  }
});

// Make this a method so that you can wire up UI buttons to skip on demand.
Future<void> skipToIndex(int i) {
  index = i;
  await player.setAudioSource(tracks[index]);
}
```