# Flutter - how to auto run a process 2 seconds after a form is displayed?

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter form where I want to auto run a process 2 seconds after a form is displayed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Future.delayed` function

```
autoRunProcess(){
 return Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
    setState(() {});
  });
}
```

You may also use `Timer`:

```
autoRunProcess(){
 return Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), (){
   setState(() {});
 });
}
```

You may find other alternatives from this reference: [How to run code after some delay in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471063/how-to-run-code-after-some-delay-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

```
void delayAction(){
  // Delay for 2 seconds
 Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
     // Call another function after the delay
     afterDelayCallFunction();
 });
}
```

Future.delayed in Dart/Flutter is a mechanism for introducing delays in asynchronous code execution. It allows you to schedule a function to be called in the future after a specified duration. This can be useful in scenarios where you want to wait for a certain period of time before executing a particular piece of code.